# Need business checking account with limited access

Tags: savings, business

I'm looking for suggestions.

I need a business checking and savings account, where I can setup full access for myself (withdrawals, deposits, view account number and routing information, etc...).

But then, for select employees (users) I would like to give them limited access to view transaction history and nothing else.

How can I do this?

Comment: Questions asking for product recommendations are considered off-topic here (as the answers can become out of date at any time). Not to mention that you don't say where you're based.

Comment: Show them copies of the bank statements?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would just show them the statements. There are also applications to import digital bank-statements and use for bookkeeping in your company. Ask your bank what formats they can provide. Some banks also offer applications for that for small-business use.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box thinking... You could open two accounts also.  One operating account and one Main Accumulation account. You give full access or limited access to your select employees to the operating account, but keep small amounts in.  Transfer daily or regular amounts to the other Main accumulation account where only you have access.  Good luck.